# How to convert an image from .bmp to .png in c++

Tags: c++, boost, png, bmp

Is there any open source C++ library using which I can convert an image present in .bmp format to .png . I went through [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) didn't find any way to do it there, while [boost/gil](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) looks complex don't know that can be used to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you solve the problem: [LodePNG](http://lodev.org/lodepng/)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see BMP in boost/GIL.. maybe take a look at Magick++ ImageMagick API
http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf

Also GDK-Pixbuf can certainly do this

Answer (score 0):

I use [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) for all my image manipulation.  Well written, with good documentation.

Comment: I have to use it for commercial purpose and its license doesn't allow this :(

Comment: Can I do it with libpng..if you have any idea.. ?

Comment: CImg is double-licensed, either GPL or CECILL-C, you can choose. And CECILL-C is close to the LGPL (it's a kind of French variant of the LGPL), so it is allowed to use CImg in closed-source products without having to release the whole code of your application. You just have to mention somewhere that you've used it.

Comment: Is the problem loading the bmp or saving as png?